# Is this code thread-safe? (function for incrementing)

Tags: c++, thread-safety

What do you think of this code below?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <thread> 
using namespace std; 
 
static int cnt=0; 

void incr_fun() 
{ 
cnt=cnt+1; // incrementing counter 
}
```

And if it is not, what should I change?
Thank you

Comment: why do you think it would be thread safe?

Comment: [Is incrementing an int effectively atomic in specific cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393850/is-incrementing-an-int-effectively-atomic-in-specific-cases) and many other questions are worth reading.

Comment: Even if `int` is fully updated in a single transaction, there's nothing to prevent the compiler from being super smart and helpful and and totally ignoring that other threads could exist while looking over the optimization options. If it decides, "No one changes `cnt` but me!" it can give you very fast, but very wrong code.

Comment: I don't know. I'm a beginner with threads.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not thread-safe.  Multiple threads *might* read `cnt` and execute `+1` at the same time, thus yielding the same result value, before any thread has assigned its result back to `cnt`. Thus `cnt` *may not* end up with the cumulative sum of the increments.

You need to use `std::atomic` or `std::mutex` or any other equivalent locking mechanism to prevent multiple concurrent access to a shared resource, eg:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <thread> 
#include <atomic>
using namespace std; 
 
static atomic<int> cnt; 

void incr_fun() 
{ 
    ++cnt; // incrementing counter 
}
```

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <thread> 
#include <mutex>
using namespace std; 
 
static int cnt = 0; 
static mutex mtx;

void incr_fun() 
{ 
    const lock_guard<mutex> grd(mtx);
    ++cnt; // incrementing counter 
} 

// make sure any other code that reads/writes
// cnt also locks/unlocks the same mutex...
```

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll study std::atomic (I'm new with these notions).